# Incorrect Class type when loading a UIViewController from Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` in my storyboard for which I have set my own custom class `MyCustomClass` (that extends `UIViewController`)

This view controller has a button in it and I show a `UIAlertView` upon a tap on this button. Simple? Here is my issue:

I get:

```
Unknown class MyCustomClass in Interface Builder file.
```

When I push the view controller to the `UINavigationController`:

```
MyCustomClass *vc = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyCustomClassView"];
NSLog(@"receiver's type: %@", NSStringFromClass([vc class]));
```

Which causes the app to crash when I tap the button inside this view controller. Any reason why that might be happening?

Comment: Did you try clean and build?

Comment: check identifier of you view controller in storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my squids target was missing the header files. Not sure why. I created a clone of the main build target and it adds properly for that.